# How to chain Laravel 5.1 (one-to-many) Eloquent ORM relationship?

Tags: orm, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Currently i am having to manually access the relationship of each event.

see below:

```
    $events = Events::where('status', '!=', 'passed')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(20)->get();
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $responses = Events::findOrFail($event->id)->responses()->where('user_id', '=', '1')->first();//TODO user_id hardcoded

        if($responses) echo "The event has a response that belongs to the user";
            else echo "The event doesnt have a response for that user";


    }
```

Is there a way to chain the "Events::" Eloquent ORM completley?

Let me know if you need to see the the models although it's pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

tried `::with` from http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships ?
Using eager loading constraints, it'll looked like

```
$events = Events::with(['response' => function($query) use($user_id){
                                      $query->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
                                      }
                       ])->where('status', '!=', 'passed')
                         ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                         ->take(20)->get();
```

However, i'm not sure how to take the first element of the constrained eager load. Try to fiddle with it more.
[Laravel Eager Load with dynamic constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542419/laravel-eager-load-with-dynamic-constraints)